# Building a computer - No boot up?

Tags: computer-building

I just build my computer, with an SSD and HDD. We turned the power switch on and the only thing that happens is two power lights in the motherboard turn on - nothing else at all. What could cause this?

Okay, a bit more detail (as much as I can give): I've just noticed that when I press the on button, all the fans move a tiny bit a top, the monitor once flashed and then immediately said no signal. It's definitely not a problem with the RAM.

Comment: Did the mother board come with a sticker "RAM and CPU sold separately"? :-)

Comment: Okay, from the -1 I'm guessing this isn't the correct place... Is there anywhere like this I could try?

Comment: @Pig: The -1 was not for posting in the wrong place, but for posting an absolutely unanswerable question and not bothering to even make a token effort to provide any details. Take a look at ESR's [excellent guide](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) on asking questions.

Comment: Just about anything could cause that, from forgetting to hook up a connection, to no RAM, like @Kerrek said.

Comment: @Ker - I would post more, but have no idea what else to post. I don't know what could cause this problem and I don't know what information to give.

Comment: @Kerrek, he's new to the site and means well from what I see. Usually we don't downvote in that case, instead we ask him to provide more information.

Comment: @Pig Head: If you can provide some more insight into what is being used as parts for the computer.

Comment: I added more detail, check OP.

Comment: @Max: Sure, and I didn't downvote, I just wanted to explain why the question is not very helpful and why people might see it as "badly presented" or "poorly researched" (as is the meaning of a downvote). I do encourage the OP to present more details and hope that there'll be a tractable cause for her problems.

Comment: It got closed, but I've no idea what else I can post. I'm worried that something might have been permanently broken, and as this computer is the absolute top of the range, I'm really worried it's not working.

Comment: BINGO! I plugged in a motherboard cable into the CPU fan slot instead of the CPU's.